Is MockObject necessary - GTest segmentation fault
Google test with fixture's got segmentation fault
Inextricably I find segmentation fault every time compiling Google unit test.
In explanation I compile Google test without problem for test without fixture.
However I must use fixture (TEST_F) to test on mock object of module with threading. Is therefore my thread construction applicable, because to the best of my knowledge I do not use nullptr in declaration anymore?
Header resembles DummyTest.h
    #ifndef CSEVCDTEST_DUMMYTEST_H
    #define CSEVCDTEST_DUMMYTEST_H
    
    class MockModule : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    
    private:
        MockModule(QObject *parent);
        ~MockModule();
        QString ident;
    
    public:
        QString getIdent();
        void setIdent(const QString &newIdent);
    };
    
    MockModule::MockModule(QObject *parent)
    {
    }
    
    MockModule::~MockModule()
    {
        delete this;
    }
    
    QString MockModule::getIdent() { return ident;}
    
    void MockModule::setIdent(const QString &newIdent) {ident = newIdent;}
    
    class MockThread : public QThread
    {
    private:
        MockThread(MockModule * mockModule);
        ~MockThread();
    
        void setThread(QThread other);
        void run() override;
    };
    
    MockThread::MockThread(MockModule *mockModule) : QThread()
    {
    }
    
    MockThread::~MockThread()
    {
    }
    
    void MockThread::setThread(QThread other)
    {
    }
    
    void MockThread::run() override
    {
        run();
    }
    
    class DummyTest : public ::testing::Test {
    protected:
        QCoreApplication * t_eventLoop;
        MockModule t_module;
        MockThread t_thread;
        void SetUp() override;
        void TearDown() override;
    
    public:
    };
    
    
    #endif //CSEVCDTEST_DUMMYTEST_H

Running tests resembles DummyTest.cpp

#include "DummyTest.h"


DummyTest::DummyTest() : ::testing::Test(),
t_eventLoop(),
t_module(&t_eventLoop),
t_thread(&t_module)
{
    
    
}

DummyTest::~DummyTest()
{
    
}

TEST(DummyTest, WillNotSegFault)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(2,3);
}

TEST_F(DummyTest, WillSegFault)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(2,3);
}

int main(int &argc, char * argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest();
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
    
}

Code does not require defs with fixture testing::NiceMock<MockThread> 
Results of working test are below
Running main() from / home/.../DummyTest
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test suite
[----------] Global test environment set-up
2 tests from DummyTest
[ RUN      ] DummyTest.WillNotSegFault
[       OK ] DummyTest.WillNotSegFault (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] DummyTest.WillSegFault
Napaka segmentacije (izpis jedra)

where error message translates: segmentation fault (core thread)
Similar implementation  with fixture testing::NiceMock<MockThread>  can compile but I do not see it feasible. Or is it necessary (fixture of child objects??

MockModule::~MockModule() { delete this; } - who did teach you this?

One problem is delete this; in MockModule::~MockModule. Since the MockModule object is not allocated with new this is going to crash. Just remove that line, or the whole destructor.

it is rare that you want to call delete in general and delete this is (almost) always wrong

MockModule name says it is a mock, implementation says it is not. Since you made other mistakes in basic area, it is clearly to early for you to talk about mocks. Please focus on mastering basics of C++ before trying understand mocks.
